# Base64 String Corrupted When Storing in Filesystem

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am working on a profile page. When the user clicks the image, they are allowed to submit a file.
I am using a file reader as such through javascript

```
          $('#profileImage').click(function(){ $('#image-file').trigger('click'); });

                $('#image-file').on('change',function(){
                    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {

                        var FR= new FileReader();

                        FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);                    
                        FR.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
                          document.getElementById("profileImage").src = e.target.result;

                          imgData = e.target.result;

                          var formData = {
                            'name'              : localStorage.getItem('email'),
                            'image'             : imgData
                          };

                            console.log("image data: " + imgData);


                            $.ajax({
                                 type   : 'POST',
                                 url    : '/uploadprofile.php',
                                 data   : formData,
                                 dataType: 'text',
                                 encode : true
                            }).done(function(data) {
                                  console.log(data);
                            });


                        });
                }





            });
```

I then have a php script that handles the base64 image string and saves it onto the filesystem.

uploadprofile.php

```
    if ($json == "") {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $image = $_POST['image'];
    } else {
        $name = $json["name"]; //within square bracket should be same as Utils.imageName & Utils.image

        $image = $json["image"];

    }


    $response = array();

   $decodedImage = base64_decode("$image");

    //unlink old picture
    // unlink($name.".jpg");
    $oldName = $name;
    $name .= date("D M d Y G:i");
    $name = str_replace(' ', '', $name);

    $fullPath = "http://www.mywebsite.com/uploads/".$name.".jpg";

    $return = file_put_contents("uploads/".$name.".jpg", $decodedImage);

    if($return !== false){
        $response['email'] = $oldName;
        $response['image'] = $image;
        $response['success'] = 1;
        $response['message'] = "Image Uploaded Successfully";
        $sql = "UPDATE Users SET PicLocation = '$fullPath' WHERE Email = '$oldName'";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    }else{
        $response['success'] = 0;
        $response['message'] = "Image Uploaded Failed";
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
```

The problem is that after I save the picture onto the filesystem, I cannot view that file, or it is corrupted somehow. Whether I use its file name for an src or directly try to view it from my control panel, it is not visible. I noticed that the file size of the base64 string is around 3 times the picture's size, which I'm not sure why that is the case.

What do I need to do so that the base64 data is made into a readable file?
The value of $decodedImage is false. What do I do to send the right format from my javascript?

The value of `$image` in php starts as follows:

> data:image/png;base64,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...

Answer (score 1):

I figured out through a blog: https://davidwalsh.name/convert-image-data-uri-javascript

All I had to do was remove the unnecessary text at the beginning of the base64 string.

Answer (score 0):

To get the base64 of the image, you should remove `data:image/png;base64,` prefix.
Plus, the image might be png for example (you may also check the validity of the type). So, you will have:

```
    $indexOfComma = strpos($image, ',');
    $imageContent = substr($image, $indexOfComma);
    $imageType = substr($image, 0, $indexOfComma);
    $imageType = str_replace(["data:image/", ";base64,"], "", $imageType); 
    $decodedImage = base64_decode("$imageContent");
    //...
    $fullPath = "http://www.mywebsite.com/uploads/" . $name . "." . $imageType;
    $return = file_put_contents($name . "." . $imageType, $decodedImage);
```